# Prolog compare list elements to Head element

Tags: prolog

I have predicate which shows all numbers which are smaller than 10.

```
    small([H|T],H):- H=<10.
    small([_|T],X):-small(T,X).
```

It is quite simple. But how should I change it so that I could compare every next item to the first element?

For example, ?- small([4,2,3,9,1,0,12],X).  would show X=2;X=3;X=1;X=0 ?

Comment: correction: that predicate shows just *one* number, first that is smaller than 10. But you force it to backtrack, by pressing `;` at the prompt. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the problem in two procedures, one that takes the first element and then applies the recursion over the remaining elements of the list and checks whether each item is less than or equal to the first element:

```
small([M|T],X):- small1(T, M, X).

small1([H|_], M ,H):- H =< M.
small1([_|T], M, X):- small1(T, M, X).
```